# Abp Dependency Injection Specify implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, abp

If there are two implementations of my encryption:

```
RSAEncryption:IEncryption
DESEncryption:IEncryption
```

How do I specify which implementation to use when injecting？

```
public myctor(IEncryption encryption) {
    // Implement is always DESEncryption
}
```

I read the relevant source code and finally found that the registration order is related to the file location. In AssemblyHelper.GetAllTypes Call:

```
public virtual Type[] GetTypes();
```

This is easy to solve in the traditional ASPNET CORE: I just need to comment out one or make the implementation I need appear in the last place.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IEncryption), typeof(RSAEncryption));
    //services.AddScoped(typeof(IEncryption), typeof(DESEncryption));
}
```

However, abp's dependency injection does not seem to provide a solution that can specify implementation or control order

Answer (score 1):

Try

```cs
context.Services.Replace(
ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IEncryption, RSAEncryption>()
);
```

Or you can use the attribute

```cs
[Dependency(ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ReplaceServices = true)]
public class RSAEncryption
```

over your class.

Here is the documentation about it: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Dependency-Injection#replace-a-service